# Firebase Scheduled Functions with schedule time less than 1 minute

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm developing a firebase scheduled function that updates my `Firestore` collection `key-values` based on some condition specified in the function. I want this scheduled function to be called every 5 seconds, but as I could understand from the firebase documents that the minimum granularity is 1 minute.

I'm thinking of using a `setInterval()` where each interval is of 5 seconds and executes the above-discussed function, but I'm not comfortable with such method, as I know this is not the correct way to do it and I may also end up incurring additional charges.

Any idea how to achieve this in a proper way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you come to any conclusions? Getting a specific function fired at 10-second intervals is something I've been needing to do, but running a functions shard doing nothing for 9s seems like a waste.

Comment: @cjcurrie We have ended up using the solution as shown in the below answer. You could improvise the same as per your requirements.

Comment: dang, I was hoping there might be another way. Looking at the pricing, I think I'll start a function-scheduler on the lowest specs, which only costs $0.20/day to run with setInterval(). Then this node can kick off other scheduled functions on higher-tier nodes.

Answer (score 1):

The immediate and easiest solution I could think of was to use Javascript Interval Timers.

Please use the below given sample code if needed,

```js
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
        // call your main function here
    }, MAIN_FUNCTION_INTERVAL * 1000);

    // Clear timers before next scheduled cycle i.e. after every 1 minute
    await new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            clearInterval(intervalId);
            resolve();
        }, (60 - MAIN_FUNCTION_INTERVAL) * 1000);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call it multiple times in one schedule event.

```
const MAX_EXECUTE_TIME =3
const SLEEP_TIME = 18

exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 1 minutes').onRun((context) => {
  for await (const executeTime of [...Array(MAX_EXECUTE_TIME)].map(
    (_, i) => i
  )) {
    console.log("every 20 seconds");
    await sleep(SLEEP_TIME); 
  }
});
```